# Can a linking verb be omitted in a parenthetical expression?

Tags: grammar, linking-verbs

> He saw us coming, and ***being*** unaware that we had learned of his
>   treachery, greeted us with a smile.

In my textbook, there is no "being", I want to know the logic or rules behind.

Comment: *was* is ungrammatical in that sentence; the missing word is *being*.

Comment: You cannot omit the verb by putting it in parentheses. You can only omit it by actually omitting it. Putting it in parentheses is the opposite of omitting it. You are calling attention to it. And the reader wonders why on Earth it's sitting in parentheses. Because the parentheses make no sense at all.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. the original sentence has no '(was)' , that was me putting it there because I wanted to know if it was correct to put it there. Peter has pointed it out that, it should be 'being' rather than 'was'. so may I ask again, in this sentence "He saw us coming, and unaware that we had learned of his treachery, greeted us with a smile." is it grammartically more correct or redandent if I put a 'being' after the 'and'?

Comment: It sounds better to me without "being". Either way I would add a comma after "and".

Comment: It's not ungrammatical to omit the 'being', but there's a loss of the 'as he was ...' sense (which makes no real difference here as context reinstates it). However, I'd add a comma if I dropped the 'being'.

Comment: The comma should be after "and", not before it. The parenthetical expression doesn't need a verb, because it's acting more like an adjective.

Comment: @Barmar It would also be fine if a comma were both before *and* after *being*. But there at least needs to be a comma after *and*.

Comment: There are discussions for the placement of the comma in the same sentence there, the comma should be placed before the "and" https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/347857/comma-placement-in-a-parenthetical-expression-preceded-by-a-conjunction

Comment: @Barmar hmm, can I write a similar sentence like "she is sitting there, and a beautiful woman, looking at me"....or "she is sitting there, and beautiful as she always is, looking at me"...?

Comment: "She is sitting there, as beautiful as usual, looking at me". No need for "and" in the parenthetical.